# Get URL Variable From Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables

I am trying to get the URL variable `ID` from a list of objects in an array and display them.

---

Current Code:

```
$display = print_r($array);
echo $display;
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => https://example.com?ID=435 [1] => https://example.com?ID=53 [2] => https://example.com?ID=5 [3] => https://example.com?ID=25 )
```

---

I would like the display each URL variable `ID` from the array inside a `<div>` element:

```
<div>435</div>
<div>53</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>25</div>
```

I have tried to do this using the following code but no luck:

```
foreach($display as $display2) {
   echo '<div>'.$_GET['ID'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: This will involve regex (regular expressions). The `$_GET` variable pulls from the current page's request and is not a function for stripping query data from a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$_GET` super global is for accessing query-string values from the current request, not for reading them out of an arbitrary url stored in a string.

But fret not, PHP's standard library has functions to help, namely [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
foreach($display as $url) {
   $queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
   parse_str($queryString, $parameters);
   echo '<div>'.$parameters['ID'].'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably something like this. You need to loop through each URL in the array and extract the ID from it. This can be done by splitting the URL at the `=` and grabbing the second portion.

```
foreach($display as $display2) {
   $stringArray = explode("=", $display2); //Break apart string at "="
   $id = $stringArray[1]; //Grab second part of split string (the ID)
   echo '<div>'.$id.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $array holds all the URLS, as shown in your example:

```
foreach($array as $v){
    $str = explode('=', $v);
    echo '<div>'.$str[1].'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is a super global that contains all of the query parameters for the page that was requested. It cannot be used on a list of url strings.

Instead, you can use a combination of [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```php
$urls = array(
    "https://example.com?ID=435",
    "https://example.com?ID=53",
    "https://example.com?ID=5",
    "https://example.com?ID=25",
);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    if(strrpos($url, "?") !== FALSE) {
        echo "<div>" . substr($url, strrpos($url, "?") + 4) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Feel free to copy and paste the above example into [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/) to verify that it works as expected.

**EDIT:**

Added `if` block around the echo to filter out urls that may not have an `ID` value.

Comment: I noticed the `+ 4` in your code. Is this how many objects in the array there are? I just posted an example; I cannot foresee how many objects there will be (it varies)

Comment: No, it's the number of characters past the query string's question mark `?` that the`substr()` operation should start from. i.e. Counting the `?` the `substr()` function should move 4 characters `?=ID` before beginning the `substr()` operation. It's an offset, since you know the query string parameter's name. However, if what was posted was an example, this would not work. It's a crude but effective way of doing what you want if the urls always have 1 parameter named `ID`. Admittedly, the other answers may be better suited if the urls are just examples.